How to print AddressId from Ink! Smart contract
Writing a smart contract with Ink! 5.0.0 and trying to print out an AccountId:
let accountId = ... // AccountId
let message = ink_prelude::format!("AccountId is {:?}", accountId);
ink::env::debug_println!(&message);

which I got from:
https://use.ink/basics/contract-debugging/
This prints out the AccountId as:
AccountId is AccountId([142, 175, 4, 21, 22, 135, ...])

What I want printed out is:
AccountId is 5FHneW ...

This seems incredibly simple, so think my understanding must be off.
Can anyone please explain if the array of Integers I am seeing printed out is expected behaviour?
If it is, how do I print what I want printed?
If not, what I might be missing?
